# Cannot find 'posts' in scope error in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm getting an error saying `cannot find 'posts' in scope`. I've been trying to check for a solution online however didn't come across which would solve this.

ContentView.swift

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List(posts) {  //error on this line
                post in
                Text(post.title)
            }
             .navigationBarTitle("Hacker News")
         }
     }
 }


  struct Results: Decodable {
      let hits: [Post]
  }

  struct Post: Decodable, Identifiable {

      var id: String {
          return objectId
      }
        let objectId: String
        let title: String
        let url: String
        let points: Int
  }
```

```
class NetworkManager {
    
    
    func fetchData() {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?tags=front_page"){
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error == nil{
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    if let safeData = data{
                        do {
                            let results=try decoder.decode(Results.self, from: safeData)
                            
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `posts` a global variable? From the code pasted, i didn't see it being declared and initialised.

Comment: Sure, you did not declare `posts` property anywhere in struct. I assume you need to start with https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

Comment: @ZaimRamlan I have updated the remaining code, please let me know can anything be done now?

Comment: @Asperi, I'll do that for now can you tell me how to fix this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cannot find 'posts' in scope

This means that you didn't create any variable called `posts`.

Also note that your code produces a warning in `NetworkManager` as well:

> Initialization of immutable value 'results' was never used; consider
> replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it

This is because the data fetched by `NetworkManager` isn't used anywhere.

In short, the problem is that `NetworkManager` isn't connected with / used by `ContentView` in any way.

---

A possible solution is to make `NetworkManager` an `ObservableObject` and create a `@Published` property of type `[Post]`:

```
class NetworkManager: ObservableObject { // make ObservableObject
    @Published var posts = [Post]() // create `posts` here
    
    func fetchData() {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?tags=front_page") {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if error == nil {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    if let safeData = data {
                        do {
                            let results = try decoder.decode(Results.self, from: safeData)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.posts = results.hits // assign fetched data to `posts`
                            }
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Now you need to *use* `NetworkManager` in `ContentView`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var networkManager = NetworkManager() // or `@ObservedObject` for iOS 13
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(networkManager.posts) { post in // use `posts` from `networkManager`
                Text(post.title)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Hacker News")
        }
        .onAppear {
            networkManager.fetchData() // fetch data when the view appears
        }
    }
}
```

---

Also you have a typo in `objectId` -> it should be `objectID`:

```
struct Post: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: String {
        return objectID
    }

    let objectID: String
    let title: String
    let url: String
    let points: Int
}
```

If you don't want to change the name, you can use `CodingKeys` instead:

```
struct Post: Decodable, Identifiable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case objectId = "objectID", title, url, points
    }
    
    var id: String {
        return objectId
    }

    let objectId: String
    let title: String
    let url: String
    let points: Int
}
```